# Proxies are not connecting. Python 3 requests module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am making a proxy scraper for one of my applications. However, when the code below is executed, all of the proxies do not work.

```
        with open("proxies.txt", "w") as f:
            print("writing proxies to the file")
            percent=0
            counted=0
            good=0
            bad=0
            for omegaproxy in writeproxies():
                annoyingshit= {
                    "http": omegaproxy
                }
                try:
                    response=requests.get("http://discord.com",proxies=annoyingshit,timeout=loadingtime,headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"})
                    if response.elapsed.total_seconds()<=float(loadingtime):
                        if response.status_code() > 199 and response.status_code() < 300:
                            f.write(omegaproxy+"\n")
                            counted+=1
                            good+=1
                except:
                    counted+=1
                    bad+=1
                    pass
                percent=int((counted/proxycount)*100)
                barprogress=int(percent/5)
                print(str(percent)+"% ["+(">"*barprogress)+("-"*(20-barprogress))+"]   "+"bad proxies: "+str(bad)+"/"+str(proxycount)+"  "+"good proxies: "+str(good)+"/"+str(proxycount),end="\r")
            f.close()
        print("\n")
        print("there were "+str(good)+" good proxies and "+str(bad)+" bad proxies")
        print("\n")
        print("added proxies to the list")
```

(If you saw that it said discord.com that is because the application relates to discord)

The writeproxies function obtains hundreds of proxies from three websites:

```
        async def proxy1(): return await a().get('https://free-proxy-list.net', timeout=30)
        async def proxy2(): return await a().get('https://www.us-proxy.org', timeout=30)
        async def proxy3(): return await a().get('https://www.sslproxies.org', timeout=30)

        def writeproxies():
            results = a().run(proxy1, proxy2, proxy3)
            proxies = ''
            for result in results:
                cells = result.html.find('td')
                stringshit = ''
                for cell in cells:
                    ctext = cell.text 
                    if not ctext.lower().islower():
                        if '.' in ctext:
                            ctext = '\n' + ctext + ':'
                        stringshit += ctext
                proxies += stringshit
            alldaproxies = []
            for proxy in proxies.split('\n'):
                if proxy != '':
                    alldaproxies.append(proxy)
            global proxycount
            proxycount=len(alldaproxies)
            print("This could take from "+str(int((len(alldaproxies)-250)*loadingtime))+" to "+str(int((len(alldaproxies)+250)*loadingtime))+" seconds")
            return alldaproxies
```

I tried using one of the proxies from the proxy websites to access the site using a different script as a test, but it kept saying "requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects." and when I changed the max redirects to 300 it said "requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 300 redirects." Am I doing something wrong with the headers that is setting off some sort of infinite redirect loop? How could I fix this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am such an idiot I have been debugging for 3 hours, but when I added "allow_redirects=False" to the request it worked.